# path difference on script vs in shell

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, path

Why is the output of $PATH different when in a script vs when running $PATH from the terminal? Even for a minimal script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH
```

it will not match what I get when typing in $PATH in the terminal. Because of this, I keep getting "command not found". How can I fix this? I'm using OSX High Sierra.

---

Ok, "export PATH" seems to have solved part of my problem. One of the programs that I am using though is dynamically linked. For some reason, even with export path it says "dyld: Library not loaded". At least now the program is in the path when called from the script. What does "export PATH" do? And how can I include the library paths as well?

Comment: Where do you run the script from?

Comment: the shell by just typing bash ./script, for example

Comment: What are the results from- `/usr/bin/grep PATH "$HOME/.bashrc"`?

Comment: What happens if you just run `./script` (may need a `chmod +x script` first)?

Comment: Please show us the contents of your script. Also, you should not just type $PATH, but rather something more like ``echo "$PATH"`` or ``env | grep -i "PATH"`` - that shows you the contents of the variable PATH, as opposed to your shell trying to run (the contents) as a command, which could present problems. Also, let's see which shell you're using: ``env | grep -i shell``. Sounds like your script isn't inheriting your environmental variables, which isn't all that unexpected IMO.. we just need to figure out why.

Comment: @harv There is no difference between `echo $PATH` and `echo "$PATH"`

Comment: that contents of the script is just that as shown. it gives a different result when I run "./script" vs "echo $PATH".

Comment: run `export PATH`, then run your script again. If the output still differs, please a) show us the different values of PATH and b) show where the PATH gets set in `.bash_profile` and friends, both by editing the question.